# How to remove or add an element to an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents that have an array field like so:

```
_id: 123
my_array_field: [ 5, 7, 4]
```

Now I want to "toggle" the existence of an element in that array in a single operation. For example if I send the value 3, it should be added to the array as it is not in there yet. If I send the value 5, it should be removed. Is it possible to do that without querying the document beforehand?

I am using the current version MongoDB (4.0.8) and the current NodeJS driver (3.2.3).

Thank you!

Comment: This on the first thought doesn't look possible, but you can use the aggregation pipelines but that will also query the document but shouldn't be as much as doing so manually

Answer (score 0):

Within Aggregate framework the document is fetched before hand at the start of pipeline and then it passes through all the stages for processing.

The "testCollection" in "testDb" has following documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb72e0010d85108dd5f05d5"),
    "my_array_field" : [ 
        5, 
        7, 
        4
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cbae5f62df7de6e1f5f6d21"),
    "my_array_field" : [ 
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ]
}
```

Following is the working code using mongodb nodejs driver v3.2.3:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'testDb';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
console.log("Connected successfully to server");

let val = [8];  //value to add into the my_array_field. And if it is already present then all its occurences are removed

const db = client.db(dbName);

const collection = db.collection('testCollection');

collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {_id : mongodb.ObjectID('5cb72e0010d85108dd5f05d5')}
    },
    {
        $project: {
            my_array_field: {
                $concatArrays: ['$my_array_field', val]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$my_array_field"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                id: "$_id",
                val: "$my_array_field"
            },
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "_id.val" : { 
                $ne : null 
            }, 
            count : {
                $lt: 2
            } 
        } 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.id",                
            my_array_field: {$push: "$_id.val"}
        }
    }
]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    console.log(err);

    //updated the aggregate pipeline result back to the collection
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: docs[0]._id},
        {$set: {my_array_field: docs[0].my_array_field}}).then(function(docs) {
        console.log("document updated!")
        client.close();
      })
  });
```

If 8 is added to the document [5,7,4], then following output generated:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb72e0010d85108dd5f05d5"),
    "my_array_field" : [ 
        8, 
        4, 
        7, 
        5
    ]
}
```

If 7 is added to the document [5,7,4], then following output generated:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb72e0010d85108dd5f05d5"),
    "my_array_field" : [ 
        4, 
        5
    ]
}
```